Google Coral + Proxmox LXC
I am not able to activate the Google Coral Stick. It is permanently displayed as ‘Global Unichip Corp.’, but it should actually be displayed under the name ‘Google’.
I used the official Google Coral documentation to install it on my node. Unfortunately, it didn't get me any further.
https://coral.ai/docs/accelerator/get-started/#runtime-on-linux
**I get the following error: **
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
python3-pycoral : Depends: python3-tflite-runtime (= 2.5.0.post1) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: python3 (< 3.10) but 3.11.2-1+b1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
